# BASCOM-AVR stk500_2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout: -1

Tags: arduino-uno, avr

Arduino Uno R3

Windows 10

Bascom AVR

The ON is alright.

The LED flickers now and then.

The RX and TX flickers when I press the program button on Bascom but then disappears almost immediately.

Hello. I have been having this trouble since yesterday. It always appears whenever I click the program button on Bascom. I feel so stupid having to Restart my PC and checking the Device Manager again and again. I am still new to this.
The COM Port is correct and everything else matches. I do not know how to solve this. Please help, I have already watched tutorials but they all assume you have great background in programming which I don't.

So I hope you can use easy terms.
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know next to nothing about Bascom, but Arduino Uno R3 does not use an STK500v2 bootloader.  It uses one that avrdude refers to as "arduino", basically a modified STK500(v1) protocol.  The arduinoisp.ino sketch also implements stk500v1.  So if you're using UNO "as a programmer", that is with arduinoisp.ino, it would also not be STK500v2.  STK500v2 has been used in some of the larger arduino "Mega" boards.

So if you have a choice of programmer, it would be "arduino" or perhaps "stk500(v1)" at 115200 baud.  If you are choosing an arduino board, it sounds like you have an Arduino Mega type board selected rather than the UNO.  If you are using arduinoisp.ino sketch, it would be stk500v1 at 19200 baud.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a different USB cable?

I was having trouble flashing and the cable turned out to be the issue.